# Datalist in xslt

Tags: asp.net, xslt, repeater, datalist

Is it possible to build an ASP.NET DataList of images with the help of XSLT?  I am able to build text boxes, drop downs and more, but not asp:DataList.

Comment: You forgot to provide the source XML document and the exact wanted output -- very few of the XSLT experts know what ASP.NET DataList is... Please, edit the question and provide the missing information.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do this by first doing the XSLT transform server-side, then using [ParseControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.templatecontrol.parsecontrol.aspx) to convert the XML to the DataList control.

But it seems like a better approach (without knowing all the details of your situation) would be to bind your DataList to a [XmlDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xmldatasource.aspx), or to a collection you create using Linq-to-XML.

Comment: Thanks for the reply i will try that and let you know if any difficulties